# Relation between the total number of edges and vertices of a $n$ dimensional hypercube and $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Is there a general formula that connects the number of edges and vertices of a $n$ dimensional hypercube to the number of dimensions, i.e. $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$?

Comment: Google is your friend. And so is Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. The number of vertices is $2^n$ and the number of edges is $n2^{n-1}$. Generally the number of $d$- dimensional elements in $n$- dimensional cube is
$$\binom nd 2^{n-d}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Literally from the first paragraph from the [Wikipedia article on the hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph):

> $Q_n$ has $2^n$ vertices, $2^{n−1}n$ edges.